# Passing WebView save state to another activity

Tags: java, javascript, android, eclipse, webview

I have activity A with a functional WebView1 and 3 buttons.  I'm saving the Webview1 state under onPause so once activity B opens the state of WebView1 is already saved.  My problem is whenever I open Activity B and try to load WebView1 save state onto WebView11 on activity B it gives me a null pointer (White Screen on phone).  How can I save the webview state of activity A so it can be restore in activity B??

Example:  Im on activity A webview on the bottom of the page I want to save that state so once I open activity 2 webview it takes me to the bottom of the same page instead of reloading the page.

Main Activity

```java
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public Bundle webViewBundle;
    WebView wv;
    Button bt1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);

        WebSettings webSettings = wv.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
        webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        wv.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
        wv.setWebViewClient(new myWebViewClient());

        addListenerOnbt1();

    }

    public void addListenerOnbt1() {

        // Select a specific button to bundle it with the action you want
        bt1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        bt1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Activity2.class);

                 Bundle name=webViewBundle;
                 intent.putExtra("name", name);

                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();

        webViewBundle = new Bundle();
        wv.saveState(webViewBundle);
    }
}
```

Activity2

```java
public class Activity2 extends Activity {

    WebView wv2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.second_main);

        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b = getIntent().getExtras();
        String name = b.getString("name");

        final RelativeLayout rl = new RelativeLayout(this);
        wv2 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView11);

        WebSettings webSettings = wv2.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        wv2.restoreState(b); // This line returns Null or white screen  

    }

}
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: have you solved it or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try saving the WebView state and starting the next activity on one go.

```
Bundle state = new Bundle();
webView.saveState(state);

Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Activity2.class);
intent.putExtra("state", state);
intent.putExtra("name", name);
```

And then restoring it from the extra.

```
webView.restoreState((Bundle)intent.getParcelableExtra("state"));
```

Comment: Thanks, it works.  Had to adjust "webView.restoreState((Bundle)intent.getParcelableExtra("state"));" to "webView.restoreState((Bundle) getIntent().getParcelableExtra("state"));" but I noticed an issue doing it this way.  For some reason the webview state gets restore on some webpages but not all of them.  Whats happening now is that on the webpages that is not restoring the page it just takes me to the top of the page instead of the correct state I was on before.  Any ideas??

Comment: I haven't tried this yet, but that sounds way cool for a new use case I may have soon!